Why did Android NDK linker remove prelink support
The prelink support was dropped in this commit https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/4688279, but does not mention any motivations. Anyone know it was dropped since it seems to me a very useful feature. And it evolves in the iOS world as "shared cache"/"mergable libraries". Any Android did not keep the support?
I would like to know the motivation.
